# Do something when user taps on UINavigationController back button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK and XCode.

I have a configuration screen and I need to save settings before user comes back to previous screen. This viewcontroller is called `SettingsViewController`.

I'm using a Navigation Controller on a Storyboard and I need to detect when user taps on Back button.

I could add this code on `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`. What do you think?
How can I detect when user taps on back button on `SettingsViewController`?

Comment: **before user comes back to previous screen -** then either make your on backButton or write your code in current `viewWillDisappear:` method ...

Comment: what you want to do when back button is pressing..

Comment: Save some settings to NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

you can add your buttonitem with self.navigationItem.leftButtonItem 
wehn the user click in the button you cal the methode defined in the selector of you button

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
//Put this viewDidLoad and make sure you have a back.png that mimics back button
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(backPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

This is your method

```
- (void)backPressed:(id)sender {
     //your code to save and also pop your view controller
  }
```

Comment: I've added a breakpoint on `- (void)backPressed:(id)sender` but it doesn't stop on it. Do I have to do something else?

Comment: No, vc isn't poped. I'm using viewWillDissaper: method. I'll try your solution later. Thanks.